# How to create d3 pie chart with percentage from non number values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

```
[{
  "sex" : "male",
  "name" : "Ted",
  "country": "USA"
}, {
  "sex" : "male",
  "name" : "Mark",
  "country": "Hungary"
}, {
  "sex" : "female",
  "name" : "Mary",
  "country": "Australia"
}, {
  "sex" : "male",
  "name" : "Valery",
  "country": "India"
}, {
  "sex" : "female",
  "name " : "Olga",
  "country": "Ireland"
}]
```

I want to convert this JSON-file to a pie chart with the help of d3.JS to show percentage of males and females. For example, there should be approximately 70% male and 30% female.
I've seen pie chart examples, but they are created from number values. One example is pretty what I want, but it is made from CSV-file: 
http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/a326c32fb44b10d979d2 - I've tried to manage this code for me, but it does not work, unfortunately:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cE77QKAeDKi304666cWJ?p=preview 
Could you give some info?

Comment: Why not convert this data structure into the correct format? I.e. count the number of males!

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but I'm not experienced in this(

Comment: Start learning Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think you need to look at how the nesting of data works. A good starting point is to read the [D3js documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) and look at [some examples on nesting data with d3](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)

If you want to create a pie chart from the number of males and females in your json you can nest your data by `sex` and then rollup by the length of the arrays created.

```
var data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.sex;
    })
    .rollup(function(d) {
        return d.length;
    }).entries(json_data);
```

To get the percentages you can loop through the nested data created and divide with the total length of your json_data.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.percentage = d.values  / json_data.length;
});
```